# How to register porter tokenizer in python

Tags: python, sqlite, full-text-search, fts3, fts4

How is the default tokenizer 'porter' in fts3 module registered.

one way to register user defined tokenizers is `fts.register_tokenizer()` but what are its arguments?

since porter being a in built tokenizer does it even need to be registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Python has the Porter tokenizer compiled in, you do not need to register it.

To register a user-defined tokenizer, you have to call the `fts3_tokenizer()` SQL function with a pointer to a C structure containing C function pointers; this cannot be easily done from Python.

Comment: I have used the `fts.register_tokenizer()` but either way i am unable to find any documentation to understand the arguments that the function requires. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I totally forgot that porter is compiled in thanks. It worked.